# Creating mongo docker container with local storage on hos

Tags: mongodb, docker

I want to run mongo db in docker container. I've pulled image and run it. So it seems work ok.

But every time I start it the DB is overwritten so I loose any changes. So I want to want to map somehow internal container storage on my local host folder.

Should I write Dockerfile or/and docker-compose.yaml? I suppose this is simple question but being new in docker I can't understand what to read to get full understanding.

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to write Dockerfile and make thing complex, just use [offical image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) as mentioned in command or compose file.

You can use both options either `docker run` or `docker-compose` but the path should be correct in mapping to keep data persistent.

Here is way

- Create a data directory on a suitable volume on your host system, e.g. `/my/own/datadir`.

Start your mongo container like this:

```
$ docker run --name some-mongo -v /my/own/datadir:/data/db -d mongo
```

> The `-v /my/own/datadir:/data/db` part of the command mounts the
>   `/my/own/datadir` directory from the underlying host system as `/data/db`
>   inside the container, where MongoDB by default will write its data
>   files.

[mongo docker volume](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)

with docker-compose

```
version: "2"
services:
 mongo:
   image: mongo:latest
   restart: always
   ports:
     - "27017:27017"
   environment:
     - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=pastime
     - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
     - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
   volumes:
     - /my/own/datadir:/data/db
```

Comment: It works. If I stop container (and have to make rm to start it again) database is overwritten. So must somehow to push mongo to use external files

Comment: `/my/own/datadir:/data/db` this will push the mongo to use db from this volume

Comment: did you use docker-compose >

Comment: `docker-compose up ` is enough